# Google Web Toolkit (GWT) web app with MySQL working fine in Eclipse but not working on openSUSE server

Tags: mysql, gwt, jdbc, opensuse

I've written a GWT web app which is hosted on an external openSUSE server. I use Google's GWT RPC to communicate with the server and send data from my client to the server where a MySQL database gets updated. Everything works perfectly fine in Eclipse but as soon as I move my /war directory to the server (including the necessary mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar file for the java-connector), the local SQL database on my server is not getting updated. Why is it not working? Is this some kind of mysql config issue?

I have set up a database on the server with the exact same name and table as the one on my local machine (where I was debugging with Eclipse). I do not get any errors from GWT (so the server access works fine) and my SQL log files also show no errors.

I have tried to restart mysql, checked that port 3306 for mysql is open and listening, disabled the firewall, and tried both localhost and 127.0.0.1 for the host.

I cannot figure out what the problem is, PLEASE someone help me! I'm going crazy here!

Here is my server side code which works fine in Eclipse but not on the server!

```
package com.mycompany.mywebapp.server;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
    GreetingService {

public String[] greetServer(String[] input) {

    //Data is entered into MySQL database on server side 
    Connection con = null; 
    Statement st = null; 

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb";
    String user = "username";
    String password = "pass";

    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password); //establishes connection to database
        st = con.createStatement(); //object for sending SQL statements to database 

        for (int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
            String DataToSend = input[i];
            String part1 = DataToSend.substring(0,DataToSend.indexOf("["));
            String part2 = DataToSend.substring(DataToSend.indexOf("["),DataToSend.indexOf("]")+1);
            //store values into mysql database
            String query = "INSERT INTO boundingboxes(name, box) VALUES('"+part1+"','"+part2+"')";
            st.executeUpdate(query);
        }

    }catch (SQLException ex){
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

    }finally{
        //make sure to avoid null pointerexception 
        try{
            if (st !=null){
                st.close();
            }
            if (con != null){
                con.close();
            }
        }catch (SQLException ex){
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    return input; 
}



}
```

Comment: your `catch (SQLException ex)` log statements are commented out. Why? Also, never use jdbc in such way! Read it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: thanks for your help. I am very new to java/mysql and this is my first ever web app. Can you explain what the best way to use jdbc is? Also, I'm not sure now to write the catch statements. Specifically how to include tools.js (used by Version.class) in my java path so I don't get a NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Read a tutorial, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html . Why do you need the `Version` class? Read a manual and tutorial for your `Logger.getLogger`. If you don't know what to do with exceptions, the best way is at least just `throw new RuntimeException(ex)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problems: 
To get rid of the NoClassDefFoundError, the external .jar files used by your app should be copied into the /WEB-INF/lib/ directly.

Apache requires an extra configuration step for jdbc-msql. Firstly, make sure that you have  set the correct GRANT permissions set up for your SQL database.

Next, follow his solution which is taken from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee.html#connector-j-usagenotes-tomcat

First, install the .jar file that comes with Connector/J in $CATALINA_HOME/common/lib so that it is available to all applications installed in the container.

Next, Configure the JNDI DataSource by adding a declaration resource to $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml in the context that defines your web application:

```
<Context ....>

...

<Resource name="jdbc/MySQLDB"
       auth="Container"
       type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<!-- The name you used above, must match _exactly_ here!

The connection pool will be bound into JNDI with the name
"java:/comp/env/jdbc/MySQLDB"
-->

<ResourceParams name="jdbc/MySQLDB">
<parameter>
 <name>factory</name>
 <value>org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory</value>
</parameter>

<!-- Don't set this any higher than max_connections on your
 MySQL server, usually this should be a 10 or a few 10's
 of connections, not hundreds or thousands -->

    <parameter>
      <name>maxActive</name>
      <value>10</value>
    </parameter>

 <!-- You don't want to many idle connections hanging around
   if you can avoid it, only enough to soak up a spike in
   the load -->

   <parameter>
    <name>maxIdle</name>
    <value>5</value>
   </parameter>

 <!-- Don't use autoReconnect=true, it's going away eventually
 and it's a crutch for older connection pools that couldn't
 test connections. You need to decide whether your application
 is supposed to deal with SQLExceptions (hint, it should), and
 how much of a performance penalty you're willing to pay
 to ensure 'freshness' of the connection -->

  <parameter>
   <name>validationQuery</name>
   <value>SELECT 1</value> <-- See discussion below for update to this option -->
  </parameter>

  <!-- The most conservative approach is to test connections
  before they're given to your application. For most applications
  this is okay, the query used above is very small and takes
  no real server resources to process, other than the time used
  to traverse the network.

  If you have a high-load application you'll need to rely on
  something else. -->

  <parameter>
   <name>testOnBorrow</name>
   <value>true</value>
  </parameter>

   <!-- Otherwise, or in addition to testOnBorrow, you can test
   while connections are sitting idle -->

   <parameter>
    <name>testWhileIdle</name>
    <value>true</value>
   </parameter>

  <!-- You have to set this value, otherwise even though
   you've asked connections to be tested while idle,
   the idle evicter thread will never run -->

 <parameter>
  <name>timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis</name>
  <value>10000</value>
 </parameter>

 <!-- Don't allow connections to hang out idle too long,
 never longer than what wait_timeout is set to on the
 server...A few minutes or even fraction of a minute
 is sometimes okay here, it depends on your application
 and how much spikey load it will see -->

 <parameter>
  <name>minEvictableIdleTimeMillis</name>
  <value>60000</value>
 </parameter>

 <!-- Username and password used when connecting to MySQL -->

 <parameter>
  <name>username</name>
  <value>someuser</value>
 </parameter>

 <parameter>
  <name>password</name>
  <value>somepass</value>
 </parameter>

 <!-- Class name for the Connector/J driver -->

 <parameter>
  <name>driverClassName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
 </parameter>

 <!-- The JDBC connection url for connecting to MySQL, notice
 that if you want to pass any other MySQL-specific parameters
 you should pass them here in the URL, setting them using the
 parameter tags above will have no effect, you will also
 need to use &amp; to separate parameter values as the
 ampersand is a reserved character in XML -->

 <parameter>
  <name>url</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</value>
 </parameter>
```